# Yolov4 error when trying to display image on custom model

Tags: cmd, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, yolo, darknet

I have trained my own model, using my own custom dataset, using Yolov4, and I have downloaded the `.cfg`, `.weights` and `.data` files.

When I try to run my model using:

```
darknet.exe detector test cfg/obj.data cfg/yolov4-og.cfg custom-yolov4-detector_best.weights
```

I get the error:

```
Error: l.outputs == params.inputs filters= in the [convolutional]-layer doesn't correspond to classes= or mask= in [yolo]-layer
```

I don't know if this is an error on my part, with the command I am running, or an error from the model I trained.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you please share your .cfg and .data files? also this could be due to incorrect output class number setup.

Comment: @Mahesh i am no longer getting that error, see my lastest post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65874720/darknet-exe-prints-out-cuda-opencv-version-when-run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are using the main darknet repo AlexeyAB. Please make sure you follow the following instructions:

1. Make sure you assign the correct `classes` number in the config file.
2. Change `filters=255` to `filters=`(classes + 5)x3 in the 3
   `[convolutional]` before each `[yolo]` layer, keep in mind that it only
   has to be the last `[convolutional]` before each of the `[yolo]` layers

   https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/0039fd26786ab5f71d5af725fc18b3f521e7acfd/cfg/yolov3.cfg#L603
   https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/0039fd26786ab5f71d5af725fc18b3f521e7acfd/cfg/yolov3.cfg#L689
   https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/0039fd26786ab5f71d5af725fc18b3f521e7acfd/cfg/yolov3.cfg#L776

   So if `classes=1` then should be `filters=18`. If `classes=2` then write `filters=21`

   (Generally filters depends on the classes, coords and number of masks, i.e. filters=(classes + coords + 1)*, where mask is indices of anchors. If mask is absent, then filters=(classes + coords + 1)*num)

Reference: https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-train-to-detect-your-custom-objects