# Darknet.exe Prints out Cuda & Opencv Version When Run

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, yolo, darknet

I have been trying to make an inference using the Yolov4 Darknet model I trained, and whenever I try to run the Command in Powershell, all It does is print out Cuda Version and OpenCv Version. If anybody has experienced this or knows a solution that would be amazing.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to specify the input file/video as the last cmd line argument to perform inference on that particular file/video.

For example:

```
input image: darknet.exe detector test cfg/coco.data yolov4.cfg yolov4.weights -ext_output dog.jpg

video: darknet.exe detector demo cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov4.cfg yolov4.weights -ext_output test.mp4

WebCam 0: darknet.exe detector demo cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov4.cfg yolov4.weights -c 0
```